# Why is this htaccess file causing a 500 error in Apache?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Why is my htaccess file causing a 500 error?

I am trying to get it so when anyone enters http://www.example.com/24 it will run the script for the 'key' 24 but the server reads http://www.example.com/?key=24.

Php script on index.php:

```
<?php include("scripts/config.php");
include("scripts/facebook.php");

if(isset($_GET['key'])){

$like_id=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['key']);

include_once 'like/index.php';

}else{

include_once 'home.php';


}
?>
```

htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/\index$ index.php?key=$1

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/\index$ index.php?key=$1
```

Also could it be where i'm saving my htaccess file? currently its in the htdocs folder.

Comment: Do you have access to the error logs? If you do, look there for the exact error message

Comment: Why do you have the same rule twice in your .htaccess file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?key=$1
```

In any case, your current rules should not trigger a 500 status code unless `mod_rewrite` is not enabled.

**Edit:** I've just noticed that you spell it `htaccess` all around the question. The correct name is `.htaccess` (note the leading dot).

Answer (score 1):

Error in your slashes

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\/index$ index.php?key=$1  
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\/index$ index.php?key=$1
```

Comment: If I'm correct, you don't even need to escape the / , so `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/index$ index.php?key=$1 ` should work.

Comment: Why is the `index` suffix required at all in the pattern?

Answer (score 0):

It might be looping through the rules over and over. Always add [L] unless you want the rules to be processed further.

Also, as point out by Alvaro, you don't need the / index part:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?key=$1 [L]
```